# can't use sscanf() in C for char array

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, scanf

I'm trying to get a very large number (more than `unsigned long long int`). So I get it as a string and then convert it, digit by digit, into integer and use it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{ 
    char m[100];
    int x;
    scanf("%s",m);
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(m); i++){
        sscanf(m[i],"%d",&x);
        printf("%d",x);
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

However, during compiling it shows:

> warning: passing argument 1 of ‘sscanf’ makes pointer from integer
>   without a cast

and

> note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char’

And, when I run program it will give me the `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`  error.

I also tried more simple code to find the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{ 
    char m[5];
    char n;
    int x;
    scanf("%s",m);
    n = m[1];
    sscanf(n,"%d",&x);  
    return 0; 
}
```

but nothing changed.

Comment: `%d` does not mean "digit" it means "signed decimal integer". But as to the error itself, `sscanf` needs a `const char *` (ie a string) but you have given a single character.

Comment: With `m` being only four characters plus a thanks, ”very long” is an appalling misnomer.  You can't safely use `%d` for really long strings of digits; the behaviour on overflow is undefined.

Comment: `sscanf(m[i],"%d",&x);` is wrong. You should do `x = m[i] - '0';` instead. and your input string is too small for a big number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scanf` doesn't apply to *characters*. Once you have the characters just convert digits to integers by subtracting `'0'` as a char:

```
for(int i=0; i<strlen(m); i++){
    x = m[i] - '0';   // line to change
    printf("%d",x);
}
```

Besides, just to make sure that the buffer won't overflow, 100 bytes is good, but you may want to use an according limit in `scanf` and check the return code:

```
if (scanf("%99s",m) == 1) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sscanf` to convert a *single digit* of a character string to an integer is the wrong approach. To do this, you only need to subtract the (integer) value of the representation of the character `'0'` from that digit. Like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char m[50]; // As pointed out, a 4-digit number isn't really very long, so let's make it bigger
    int x;
    scanf("%49s", m); // Limit the input to the length of the buffer!
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(m); i++) { // The "strlen" function return "size_t"
        x = m[i] - '0'; // The characters `0` thru `9` are GUARANTEED to be sequential!
        printf("%d", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```